# How to detect the interesting point of an object in a video?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

Let say I have this drive recorder video. So, I want to track the interesting points of a car from the video. I know I can use the SIFT descriptor (and other kind of similar descriptors), but with this method, I will detect all kind of interesting points in the whole image (not just the car's). My solution is to apply HOG descriptor to detect the car first, and then, the car's interesting points but I think this is really not the right way.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track the interest points of a moving car - from a moving camera - you HAVE to know which points lie on the car. That means you need to know where the car is. So the problem is really - how do you determine the bounding box for a car so that you can extract interested points from it? You pretty much need a car detector for that. You can build a dedicated car classifier trained on car images or you might be able to use optical flow tracking to figure out what's background and what looks like a car.

Answer (score 0):

if background of videos is static, use frame difference and then extract moving objects by region growing method. for speed up this process you can run region growing, when result of frame difference (number of pixel) are bigger than specific threshold. 
after extraction of moving objects(in your case "car") use SIFT descriptor

Comment: How if the image is not static? Which means both the video and the car is moving? I have a thought of using HOG descriptor that only detect some parts of the cars, but I don't know if it is the right/best way.